# ASP.NET getting data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to get the name of the employee from the database and fill it in the textbox for the respective employee id.

I tried this code but nothing is happening on the page. It just reloads and the textbox (name) is left blank only.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-0FUUV7B\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDetails;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
           
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ProfessionalDetails where EmpId='"+EmployeeId.Text+"'", con);
          
SqlDataReader da = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (da.Read())
{
    Name.Text = da.GetValue(1).ToString();
}
            
con.Close();
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Did you debug it and found where is problem because at high level code looks fine so there is alot of possibilities of issue like EmployeeId.Text is null, not able to connect to db,da.GetValue(1) is null. So first add try and catch then debug it and find the line where it is the  issue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution is to execute the sql statement through Parameterized value.
The details of that process is given below:

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(live_connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Query", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", employeeId);

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                var ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
             

                string? name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[1]["Variable name"].ToString();
              
              Name.Text =name;
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: `AddWithValue` is also not a good solution, [it's "evil"](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: If you don't want to specify the type of the params then you should use this functions,
Not bad to use that , its also prevent us in Sql Injections

Comment: Other way of using Add() function which hold type as well, that what i talked about in previous comment.

Comment: *"Not bad to use that"* it certainly can be; the data types it passes can be the *wrong* data type and cause the query to be non-SARGable. That is *bad*, and can be *awful* for performance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above in comments, you have lot of issues.

you should use using with the connection to dispose of them.

You should use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection.

Put your code in try catch so that you can easily identify the root cause of the issue.

Define the connection string in config file three than defining in the c# code.

You don’t need to select all the columns. And please avoid `select *` in the query, instead just write your column name, as you want to select only one column here.

You can use [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_ExecuteScalar), it’s used when you are expecting single value.

And first make sure that textbox has the expected value when you are calling this query.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, use paramters, and BETTER use STRONG typed paramters.

And no need to use a dataset, this is a single table - so use a datatable.

thus:

```
        string strSQL = 
            @"select * from ProfessionalDetails where EmpId= @ID";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = EmployeeID.Text;
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                if (rstData.Rows.Count > 0)
                    Name.Text = rstData.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
            }
        }
```